# Excel count days in each month between two dates spanning over a year

Tags: excel

[Screen Shot of the Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKcq3.png)I have utilised  Sumproduct solution in a spreadsheet I have, however, the issue I have now is the fact that if I bridge across a 12 month period then I get the months for both years populated, my formula is as follows;

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR($B9="",$B9<>"Liverpool"),"",IF($F9="","",IF((SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($F9&":"&IF($G9="",TODAY(),$G9))))=MONTH(L$7)))$H9)=0,"",(SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($F9&":"&IF($G9="",TODAY(),$G9))))=MONTH(L$7)))$H9)))),"")
```

Any help in solving this issue will be very much appreciated

Comment: between is not a good tag for this question. use excel instead as tag, at least as an additional one

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and the desired result?